# Django value too long for type character varying(20) error after migration from sqlite to postgree

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a slightly weird issue:
After migration from sqlite to postgree I am keep getting this error from db backend:

> value too long for type character varying(20)

code of this field is like bellow:

```py
boat_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="Boat model", help_text="Please input boat model")
```

all migrations has been made and ran

max_length has been changed in PGADMIN to 50 – no effect.

Command:

```sql
ALTER TABLE boats_boatmodel  ALTER COLUMN boat_name TYPE VARCHAR(50)
```

has been ran -no effect.

What it might be?

Will changing to TextField with CharField widget be helpful in this case???

Thank you!

migration:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='ExtraUser',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('username', models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, verbose_name='first name')),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, verbose_name='last name')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, verbose_name='email address')),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
                ('is_activated', models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=True, verbose_name='Is user activated?')),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'user',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'users',
                'abstract': False,
            },
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='BoatImage',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('boat_photo', models.ImageField(blank=True, help_text='Please attach any photo of the boat', upload_to='photos/', verbose_name='Boat photo')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Boat photo',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'Boat photos',
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='BoatModel',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('boat_name', models.CharField(db_index=True, help_text='Please input boat model', max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name='Boat model')),
                ('boat_length', models.FloatField(help_text='Please input boat water-line length', verbose_name='Boat water-line length')),
                ('boat_description', models.TextField(blank=True, help_text='Please describe the boat', verbose_name='Boat description')),
                ('boat_mast_type', models.CharField(choices=[('SL', 'Sloop'), ('KE', 'Ketch'), ('YA', 'Yawl'), ('CK', 'Cat Ketch')], default='SL', help_text='Please input boat rigging type', max_length=10, verbose_name='Boat rigging type')),
                ('boat_price', models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(help_text='Please input boat price', verbose_name='price of the boat')),
                ('boat_country_of_origin', models.CharField(help_text="Please specify boat's country of origin", max_length=20, verbose_name='Boat country of origin')),
                ('boat_sailboatdata_link', models.URLField(blank=True, help_text='Please type in URL to Sailboatdata page for this boat', max_length=100, verbose_name='URL to Sailboatdata')),
                ('boat_keel_type', models.CharField(help_text="Please specify boat's keel type", max_length=50, verbose_name='Boat keel type')),
                ('boat_publish_date', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('boat_primary_photo', models.ImageField(help_text='Please attach a primary photo of the boat', upload_to='photos/', verbose_name='Boat primary photo')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Boats primary data',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'Boats primary data',
                'ordering': ['boat_name'],
            },
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='boatimage',
            name='boat',
            field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='boats.BoatModel', verbose_name='Boat ForeignKey'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Can you show your migration file?

Comment: @arikan. I have added the migration file